# How to modifie a variable that its inside on a file on C?

Tags: c, database, file

I'm new in coding, tecnically i started this year to code and i need a lot of practise. Whatever, i tried to modify a variable that is in a file but the browser or CPU didnt found it. When i run the code, it can write the variables and pass it to the file and read it, but it cant modifie a variable that is inside on the file. I tried to use a while and an if but my knowledge couldnt go so far than these.

The problem is on the Delete function, it can read the file or archive but it couldnt reach the "end of file" because apparently it doesnt exist. The code principally read a punch of number and stop when you enter -1 on the scanf. The it read all the number (include -1 twice) and then it modifie the last number converting to a zero. The problem is that the last function repeated infinitely

```
#include<stdio.h>
void Create(FILE *p){
p=fopen("c:Example", "rb");
if(!p){
    p=fopen("c:Example", "wb");
    printf("El texto fue creado \n");
    } else {
    printf("El texto ya existe \n");
    }
}
void Add(FILE *p){
int a;
p=fopen("c:Example", "ab");
if(p==NULL){
    printf("El texto no se encontro \n");
    } else {
    scanf("%d", &a);
    while(a!=-1){
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
        scanf("%d", &a);
        }
    fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
    }
fclose(p);
}
void Read(FILE *p){
int a;
p=fopen("c:Example", "rb");
if(p==NULL){
    printf("El texto no existe \n");
    } else {
    fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
    printf("%d \n", a);
    while(a!=-1){
        fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
        printf("%d \n", a);
        }
    }
fclose(p);
}
void Delete(FILE *p){
int a;
p=fopen("c:Example", "wb");
if(p==NULL){
    printf("El texto no existe \n");
    } else {
    fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
    printf("(1)\n");
    while(a!=-1){
        fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
        printf("(2)\n");
        }
    a=0;
    printf("(3)\n");
    }
fclose(p);
}

int main(){
FILE *p;
Create(p);
printf("\n");
Add(p);
printf("\n");
Read(p);
printf("\n");
Delete(p);
printf("\n");
Read(p);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be checking the return value of `fread`. When end of file (EOF) has been reached, it will return 0 instead of 1. You can then call the function [`feof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) to determine whether the reason for not receiving more data was because EOF was reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to the problem could be reading the numbers and generate a new file with the last number, which is -1, replaced by 0. Then delete the old file and rename temporary file as the older one. I wrote a solution that works trying to not change much code of yours. I suggest you to better undestand how **fread()** and **fwrite()** functions work. After scanf function, I use **getchar()** function to remove new line, caused when you hit enter, from the buffer. Try also to keep your code clean with spaces and indent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Create (FILE *p)
{

    if((p = fopen ("c:Example", "wb")) == NULL) // Check if file opening doesn't fail
    {
        printf ("Can't open file\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    printf ("File exists\n");

    fclose (p); //Close file pointer
}

 void Add(FILE *p)
{
    int a = 0; // Initialize variable

    p = fopen("c:Example", "ab");

    if (p == NULL) // File opening failed
    {
        printf("El texto no se encontro \n");
        exit (-1); // Program has to terminate
    } 
    else 
    {

        while(a != -1)
        {
            printf ("Please insert number\n"); //Tell user what to do
            scanf ("%d", &a);
            getchar();
            fwrite(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
        }
    }

    fclose(p);
}

void Read(FILE *p)
{
    int a = 0; // Initialize variable
    p = fopen("c:Example", "rb");

    if(p == NULL) // Error opening file
    {
        printf("El texto no existe \n");
        exit (-1); // Program has to termimate
    } 
    else 
    {
        while(a != -1)
        {
                fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);
                printf("I've read %d\n", a);
        }
    }

    fclose(p);
 }

 void Delete(FILE *p)
 {
     int a = 0;
     p = fopen("c:Example", "r"); //Open for read

     if(p == NULL) // Can't open file
     {
         printf("El texto no existe \n");
         exit (-1); //Exit the program
     } 

     else 
     {
        FILE *temp;
        if ((temp = fopen ("temp", "ab")) == NULL) //Create a temp file in append mode
         {
             printf ("Error creating temp file\n");
             fclose (p);
             exit (-1);
         }

         while (a != -1)
         {
             fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, p);

             if (a != -1)
             {
                  fwrite (&a, sizeof(int), 1, temp); // write to temp only if is not -1
             }
         }

         a = 0;
         fwrite (&a, sizeof (int), 1, temp); //Write 0 to last position

         fclose (temp);
         fclose (p);
         remove ("c:Example"); //Remove old file
         rename ("temp", "c:Example"); //Rename new file
         }
  }

  void Read_new (FILE * p)
  {
     int a = -1 // Initialize a as -1;
     p = fopen ("c:Example", "rb");

     while (a != 0)
     {
          fread (&a, sizeof (int), 1, p);
          printf ("I've read %d\n", a);
     }

    fclose (p);
 }

 int main()
 {
    FILE *p;
    Create(p);
    Add(p);
    Read(p);
    Delete(p);
    Read_new(p);
    return 0;
 }
```